# Resources for JUnit testing of a class

Tags: java, junit

As an exercise, I need to learn to write tests on the following class:

package bankAccount;

```
public class CurrentAccount {

        int account[];
        int lastMove;

        CurrentAccount() {
            lastMove = 0;
            account = new int[10];
        }

        public void deposit(int value) {
            account[lastMove] = value;
            lastMove++;
        }

        public void draw(int value) {
            account[lastMove] = value;
            lastMove++;
        }

    public int settlement() {
           int result = 0;
           for (int i=0; i<account.length; i++) {
                  result = result + account[i];
               }
               return result;
         }


        public static void main(String args[]) {
                 CurrentAccount c = new CurrentAccount();
                  c.deposit(10);
        }
    }
```

I am relatively new to Unit testing, and a lot of the tutorials simply cover how to do tests for simple Mathematical operators (e.g. add, subtract etc).  Can anyone recommend good resources for doing Unit testing of more complex functions?  Am I best off using

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

and working from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be testing against the specification of the object e.g.

1. what's the starting balance ?
2. what's the balance after I add £10 ?
3. can I go overdrawn ?

etc. All the above should be specified prior to writing the class (otherwise, how do you know what to write?)

I would create a test method for each of these scenarios, perform a setup and the action, and then use one (or more, if necessary) `asserts` to determine that all is well. Don't forget that in some cases you may be testing that an exception is thrown, and consequently you will want to check for a break in control flow. That wouldn't use `assert`.

Here's a possible example (imports etc. omitted)

```
public void testBalanceAfterTenPoundDeposit() {
   // note the interface/impl separation so I can test different
   // implementations with the same interface (this is Test By Contract)
   CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccountImpl();

   // check the starting balance
   Assert.assertEquals(ca.settlement(), 0);

   // deposit
   ca.deposit(10);

   // do I have £10 ?
   Assert.assertEquals(ca.settlement(), 10);
}
```

It's important to note that this sort of testing should really be focused on the component (unit) as a black box. That is, the test should really be agnostic to the implementation and you wouldn't explicitly test the array implementation. I should be able to insert my own implementation (or rewrite yours) and the tests should remain working (that's the principle of a *regression* test).

Having said that, if you know of obvious limitations of the implementation (e.g. your fixed size array) you should try and stress that (e.g. in this situation, perform 11 inserts)

Comment: OK.  Presumably the starting balance would be listed as a float?  Where would it go in the code?  Would it be right at the the beginning?  With going overdrawn, would I best off getting it to do a System.out.println displaying an error message when the overall balance goes below 0?

Comment: These are design issues, rather than testing issues. I note you're storing transactions and derive the balance via the settlement() method, so you don't *have* a starting balance, other than the initial value in the settlement() method. What do you do if you go overdrawn ? That's a specification issue. You could throw an exception. Or issue an alert. Or just accept it and have another process monitor accounts with a -ve balance.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Are you able to write out a sample test for how to test an array (e.g. the settlement one), to help me get my head round array testing?

Comment: See my comments above re. implementation testing. I wouldn't normally *explicity* test the implementation unless I know of particular quirks/limitations that could be exploited (that's perhaps a pointer to an implementation issue...)